# Android: get real screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

Since API 17 it is possible to get the actual screen size of a phone with:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
            display.getRealSize(size);
            int screen_width = size.x;
            screen_height = size.y;
} else {...}
```

I want to get the real screen size for APIs 8-16. What is the best way to handle the else condition in this case?

Comment: Doesn't that entirely depend on the purpose of your app?

Comment: @slhck you are right, just made an edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is my solution for getting the actual screen height on all APIs. When the device has a physical navigation bar, `dm.heightPixels` returns the actual height. When the device has a software navigation bar, it returns the total height minus the bar. I have only tested on a few devices but this has worked so far.

```
int navBarHeight = 0;
Resources resources = context.getResources();
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    navBarHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}

DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

boolean hasPhysicalHomeKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
    display.getRealSize(size);
    int screen_width = size.x;
    screen_height = size.y;
} else if (hasPhysicalHomeKey){
    screen_height = dm.heightPixels;
} else {
    screen_height = dm.heightPixels + navBarHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
display.getRealSize();
```

More about visited this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html

or

You look at url:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/3821823

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Comment: display.getRealSize() is only available in API 17+ so wouldn't be usable in API 8-16 as the question asked

Answer (score -2):

```
else{
   display.getWidth()
   display.getHeight()
}
```

**edit:** alternative solution

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
metrics.widthPixels
metrics.heightPixels
```

from the docs:

> The absolute width of the display in pixels.

if even after those method the device insist in not giving it's real size, I don't believe there will be much you can do without editing the `build.prop` file on the device.

Comment: Will this include the software navigation bar size?

Comment: I've tried on a ZTE U930HD with Android 4.1 and it returns 1184 (the total height minus the navigation bar)